# Using Eloquent With the LIKE Operator

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I want to make a query that has multiple filters using LIKE.

**Example**

```php
$ingresosTerminadosDesechados = Ingreso::join('solicitudes', 'ingresos.solicitud_id', '=', 'solicitudes.id')
    ->join('articulos', 'ingresos.articulo_id', '=', 'articulos.id')
    ->join('clientes', 'solicitudes.cliente_id', '=', 'clientes.id')
    ->select('ingresos.id', 'ingresos.fecha_culminacion', 'ingresos.total_ingreso', 'ingresos.estatus_ingreso',
        'solicitudes.id as id_solicitud', 'articulos.sku_articulo', 'articulos.serie_articulo',
        'articulos.peso_articulo', 'articulos.unidad_masa_articulo')
    ->where('solicitudes.cliente_id', '=', $clienteConectado)
    ->where('ingresos.solicitado_envio', '=', 'N')
    ->where('articulos.sku_articulo', 'LIKE', '%' . trim($request->filtro) . '%')
    ->orWhere('articulos.serie_articulo', 'LIKE', '%' . trim($request->filtro) . '%')
    ->whereIn('ingresos.estatus_ingreso', ['Terminado', 'Desechado'])
    ->orderBy('ingresos.estatus_ingreso', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

With a single LIKE it works perfect, but if I add more fields LIKE does not do the job properly, where is my error?

I hope you can help, thanks.

Comment: Are you receiving any error messages ?

Comment: No ... I do not receive an error, but I do not apply the filters correctly, it brings me some information that is not correct, if I apply a single LIKE it works very well, the problem is when I add another field to execute the LIKE

Comment: can you describe the problem a bit more What is the input what is the output what is the expected output what does the source data look like ?

Comment: The idea is to filter using the LIKE statement, as you can see, where I am using LIKE I want to find information whether it matches one field or the other, the problem is that the query does not run correctly, the filter brings information that does not is the one I'm asking, so I want to know if the way I'm doing the query with Eloquent has some error.

Comment: could it be because you are using an OR improperly? Make sure your intent is being met with that OR. I don't know eloquent, but I know SQL

Comment: can you explain it a bit more? Can you show sample code of what it like running with a single `like`? It might be you are using `where` and `orWhere` differently. Make sure what you are willing to get.

Comment: your query get records that have entire or part of $request->filtro value in sku_articulo or serie_articulo value and its no problem:)

Comment: That is the problem. If I execute the query with SQL flat it works perfect, but when I try to use eloquent it is that it gives me the problem of fetching repeated data or that I am not consulting.

Comment: @markg How should I use the or in this case? it happens that I am saying: Filter by sku_articulo OR filter by serie_articulo That is, I tell him to look for that OR field for the other field. As it should be placed in Eloquent.